# Sails API (Ember frontend) rejecting changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, sails.js

I'm getting started with Ember (CLI) and am trying to create a simple CRUD setup, using Sails as my API. Ember's loading all the data as expected, but won't save any changes. I've made some actions buttons to toggle Booleans, and increment a counter, but these just revert back. However, Sails' default attribute "updatedAt" is updated with the date of the attempted update.

It seems GET and DELETE work fine, but am I perhaps missing a step for PUT and POST to work properly?

I'm using the mphasize's sails-ember-blueprints, but haven't read about much trouble with them.
[here](https://github.com/mphasize/sails-generate-ember-blueprints)

Comment: Have you had a look at the http://sanestack.com it is a CLI combining sails.js on the back end and ember.js on the frontend. Here is the chatroom for the project https://gitter.im/artificialio/sane

Comment: Yeah thanks. Had a couple of little issues getting set up properly and with docker on Windows so I thought I might try and figure out both a bit separately first, then come back to it. I'm hoping someone might be able to point out something stupid that might be missed, but yeah, I'll get back to setting Sane up properly a little later I think. Cheers

Comment: Must also say the Sane team were really helpful and immediately corrected an issue we found with Sane on Windows.

Comment: #rjoxford, I had heard the sane guys are super great.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had some issues with plurality. The model title in the json payload was singular, and the backend plural. Took a little rejigging, but this was only a simple test project.

Comment: You should check out the ember blueprints - I use it in https://github.com/wayne-o/sonatribe-api

Comment: That's if you don't want to go full hog and do the sane stack route - sane stack is immense but i wanted it nearer to the metal as a learning process for me

Comment: Yeah I thought I'd try a little without sane too, but come back to Sane. Still struggling to work out what sort of plurality everything ought to be, whats done automatically etc.